# IsError (GetObject(, "word.application")) is returning an error when word is not running instead of returning true

Tags: excel, vba

So I am working on opening a series of files from excel, manipulating them, and saving them as PDF.  I was thinking that it would be better to start MSWord before going into the loop that opens each files then closes the file instead of starting and closing word for each file.  That got me thinking that I also should not start word if it is already running.

I was trying to avoid using `on error resume next` so I tried the following code:

```
If IsError(GetObject(, "word.application")) Then
    Set MSWordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    MSWordVisState = False
    AlreadyRunning = False
Else
    Set MSWordApp = GetObject(, "word.application")
    MSWordVisState = MSWordApp.Visible
    AlreadyRunning = True
End If
```

Which works great... AS LONG AS WORD IS ALREADY RUNNING!!!!

If word is not already running ISERROR returns and error instead of returning true.  What am I missing/not understanding?

Is there a method for testing without using `on error resume next`?  I swear I have stumble on this concept in the past but am having difficulties find it now.

**UPDATE**

The error code for those that may be wondering is "Run-time error '429':  ActiveX component can't create object"

**What I am currently using**

```
    On Error GoTo StartWord
        Set MSWordApp = GetObject(, "word.application")
        MSWordVisState = MSWordApp.Visible
        AlreadyRunning = True
        GoTo WordGood

StartWord:
    Set MSWordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    MSWordVisState = False
    AlreadyRunning = False
    On Error GoTo 0

WordGood:
    MSWordApp.Visible = False
    'Carry on with rest of MAIN sub

MSWordApp.Visible = MSWordVisState
If Not AlreadyRunning Then MSWordApp.Quit
```

Comment: @braX That returns the same error I was getting during the IsError attempt

Comment: Yeah, i guess so - I think you will just have to error trap it.

Comment: `IsError` only works with error **values** not run-time errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsError` can't handle this error. Use `On Error Resume Next` as shown below

```
Dim oWordApp As Object

'~~> Establish an Word application object
On Error Resume Next
Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
```